# JS - reserverd words inside object

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

There is a list of js reserved words [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). The word "class" is reserved. I have the following code:

```
var Foo={
   class:function(){
   ...
   }
}
```

In all browsers (opera,ff,chrome,ie9,safari) my code works without any problems (no error nor notifications). Now I need to obfuscate my code. Fot that I use [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) (writtend in java). And in line "class" it shows invalid property id and syntax error. Everything is ok when I changed class to clazz.

So my question - is it bug in YUI or my code is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With help of Hrishi I found the answer. YUI uses Rhino 1.7 and it's the only that doesn't support reserved words as property names. See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Answer (score 1):

Since ES-5, you can use keywords for property names, so your code is fine.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me hint and I found the full answer.